# Number in excel is returned as a double number

Tags: apache-poi

I am using POI to read an excel. In some point I read a cell

```
while(rowIterator.hasNext()) { //read the rows
    Row row = rowIterator.next();
    String quantity = row.getCell(4).toString(); // it returns a string in 1000.0 
}
```

Why I get a string `1000.0` and not `1000` ? The values in the excel are in General format, without the `.` e.g 1000, 234, 33, 102 etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `toString()` method on cell will return the String representation of the cell value. 
If you are sure your cell will return Number then you should use [getNumericCellValue()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getNumericCellValue()) on cell.

i.e

```
row.getCell(4).getNumericCellValue()
```

Comment: Great! thx for the info!